# How to make sed omit not matching lines?

Tags: regex, sed, bash-scripting

In the following example, `sed` matches lines starting with an `a` or a `c` and prints the first character of that line (`a` or `c`):

```
$ echo "ag
bh
ci
dj
ek
fl" | sed 's/\(a\|c\)./\1/' # Matches lines starting with 'a' or 'c'.

output:
a
bh
c
dj
ek
fl
```

However, the lines that do not match the pattern are also printed out. How do I tell `sed` to omit the lines that doesn't match the pattern? I can obtain the desired effect by combining it with `grep` (as follows) but I would like to know if `sed` can achieve that "by itself".

```
$ echo "ag
bh
ci
dj
ek
fl" | grep '[ac]' | sed 's/\(a\|c\)./\1/'

output:
a
c
```

Comment: It doesn't matter for what you really wanted to know, but your pattern should start with ^ so it's anchored to the beginning of the line.  As coded, it would match an a or c anywhere in the line as long as it's not the last character.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `no-print` flag (`-n`) and explicitly print successful substitute commands (`s///p`):

```
 sed -n 's/\(a\|c\)./\1/p'
```